# How to create an "Effect Aura" for players?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a custom item called a "Medigun" in Minecraft. Simply put, when you hold a skull with the name "Medigun", it activates a /execute command. I am trying to make it so that when you hold it, it gives an effect of Regeneration III to every entity around it within 4 blocks. So far, I have the command

> /execute @a ~ ~ ~ /effect @e[r=4] minecraft:regeneration 10 2

set up, but when I hold it, all players on the server get Regeneration III. How can I make it so that only players near me will get this effect?

Answer (score 2):

Use tags to target only players who are holding the gun.

Repeat block:

`/scoreboard players tag @a remove HoldingGun`

Chain blocks, in order:

`/scoreboard players tag @a add HoldingGun {SelectedItem:{display:{Name:"Medigun"}}}`

`/execute @a[tag=HoldingGun] ~ ~ ~ /effect @e[r=4] minecraft:regeneration 10 2`

Of course, I'm just assuming the Medigun item has a display name of Medigun; if it has other special tags, you should change those in the first command accordingly. (And I highly recommend including the item id inside the SelectedItem tag as well, so that people can't just rename other items to Medigun and get the effect.)